# GWT ValueListBox, Renderer and ProvidesKey

Tags: gwt

How to implement a GWT ValueListBox inside an Editor with a specific list of objects, my code:

```
...
@UiField(provided = true)
@Path("address.countryCode")
ValueListBox<Country> countries = new ValueListBox<Country>(
        new Renderer<Country>() {

            @Override
            public String render(Country object) {
                return object.getCountryName();
            }

            @Override
            public void render(Country object, Appendable appendable)
                    throws IOException {
                render(object);
            }
        },          
        new ProvidesKey<Country>() {
            @Override
            public Object getKey(Country item) {
                return item.getCountryCode();
            }

        });
...
```

The Country class

```
public class Country  {
    private String countryName;
    private String countryCode;
}
```

But, during the GWT compilation I'm getting this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Country
```

Comment: Could you attach the class you making editor for? Which contains Country field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to edit the `address.countryCode` (looking at the path annotation) with editor for `Country`.
To make this work, you should change the path to `address.country` and do the assignment of the `address.countryCode` after `editorDriver.flash()`. Something like:

```
Address address = editorDriver.flush();
address.setCountryCode(address.getCountry().getCountryCode());
```

**To support this, the Address class should have the Country object as property.**

You may have assumed that the ValueListBox will work like classical `select` where the key is assigned to the property. Here the whole object is assigned. So in your case `Country` object can not be assigned to `address.countryCode` and vice-versa.

Btw. you can correct the renderer (like the code below) and take care of `null` objects as arguments in the *Renderer* and *Key Provider*.

```
new Renderer<Country>() {
...
            @Override
            public void render(Country object, Appendable appendable)
                    throws IOException {
                appendable.append(render(object));
            }
...
}
```